# Calcite SQLParser is threadsafe .?

Tags: apache-calcite

while running a test like this, getting into different exceptions with each test run.

```
private static void testInParallelCaliciteParser() {
    SqlParser parser = SqlParser.create("select * from test",
            SqlParser.configBuilder().setConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.DEFAULT).build());
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Runnable runnableTask = () -> {
        Instant startTime = Instant.now();
        try {
            //synchronized (parser) {                   
                SqlNode parseQuery = parser.parseQuery("select COUNT(*) FROM common.test_table");
            //}
            System.out.println(new Date() + " [" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + "] after parsing qry, time taken in millis >> "
                    + Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()).toMillis());
        } catch (SqlParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    IntStream.range(0, 4).forEach(i -> executor.submit(runnableTask));
}
```

here is the exception.

org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Encountered "elect" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
"ABS" ...
"ALTER" ...
"ARRAY" ...
"AVG" ...
"CALL" ...
"CARDINALITY" ...
"CASE" ...
"CAST" ...
"CEIL" ...
"CEILING" ...
"CHAR_LENGTH" ...
"CHARACTER_LENGTH" ...
"CLASSIFIER" ...
"COALESCE" ...
"COLLECT" ...
"CONVERT" ...
"COUNT" ...
"COVAR_POP" ...
"COVAR_SAMP" ...
"CUME_DIST" ...
"CURRENT" ...
"CURRENT_CATALOG" ...
"CURRENT_DATE" ...
"CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP" ...
"CURRENT_PATH" ...
"CURRENT_ROLE" ...
"CURRENT_SCHEMA" ...
"CURRENT_TIME" ...
"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ...
"CURRENT_USER" ...
"CURSOR" ...
"DATE" ...
"DELETE" ...
"DENSE_RANK" ...
"DESCRIBE" ...
"ELEMENT" ...
"EVERY" ...
"EXISTS" ...
"EXP" ...
"EXPLAIN" ...
"EXTRACT" ...
"FALSE" ...
"FIRST_VALUE" ...
"FLOOR" ...
"FUSION" ...
"GROUPING" ...
"HOUR" ...
"INSERT" ...
"INTERSECTION" ...
"INTERVAL" ...
"JSON_ARRAY" ...
"JSON_ARRAYAGG" ...
"JSON_EXISTS" ...
"JSON_OBJECT" ...
"JSON_OBJECTAGG" ...
"JSON_QUERY" ...
"JSON_VALUE" ...
"LAG" ...
"LAST_VALUE" ...
"LEAD" ...
"LEFT" ...
"LN" ...
"LOCALTIME" ...
"LOCALTIMESTAMP" ...
"LOWER" ...
"MATCH_NUMBER" ...
"MAX" ...
"MERGE" ...
"MIN" ...
"MINUTE" ...
"MOD" ...
"MONTH" ...
"MULTISET" ...
"NEW" ...
"NEXT" ...
"NOT" ...
"NTH_VALUE" ...
"NTILE" ...
"NULL" ...
"NULLIF" ...
"OCTET_LENGTH" ...
"OVERLAY" ...
"PERCENT_RANK" ...
"PERIOD" ...
"POSITION" ...
"POWER" ...
"PREV" ...
"RANK" ...
"REGR_COUNT" ...
"REGR_SXX" ...
"REGR_SYY" ...
"RESET" ...
"RIGHT" ...
"ROW" ...
"ROW_NUMBER" ...
"RUNNING" ...
"SECOND" ...
"SELECT" ...
"SESSION_USER" ...
"SET" ...
"SOME" ...
"SPECIFIC" ...
"SQRT" ...
"STDDEV_POP" ...
"STDDEV_SAMP" ...
"SUBSTRING" ...
"SUM" ...
"SYSTEM_USER" ...
"TABLE" ...
"TIME" ...
"TIMESTAMP" ...
"TRANSLATE" ...
"TRIM" ...
"TRUE" ...
"TRUNCATE" ...
"UNKNOWN" ...
"UPDATE" ...
"UPPER" ...
"UPSERT" ...
"USER" ...
"VALUES" ...
"VAR_POP" ...
"VAR_SAMP" ...
"WITH" ...
"YEAR" ...
<UNSIGNED_INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
<APPROX_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
<DECIMAL_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
<BINARY_STRING_LITERAL> ...
<QUOTED_STRING> ...
<PREFIXED_STRING_LITERAL> ...
<UNICODE_STRING_LITERAL> ...
"(" ...
<LBRACE_D> ...
<LBRACE_T> ...
<LBRACE_TS> ...
<LBRACE_FN> ...
"?" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
<BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
<QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
<BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
 ...
<UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...

```
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.convertException(SqlParserImpl.java:365)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.normalizeException(SqlParserImpl.java:150)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.handleException(SqlParser.java:148)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:163)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:178)
at com.apporchid.cloudseer.db.qry.helper.TestMultiThreadSafe.lambda$5(TestMultiThreadSafe.java:142)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "elect" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
"ABS" ...
"ALTER" ...
"ARRAY" ...
"AVG" ...
"CALL" ...
"CARDINALITY" ...
"CASE" ...
"CAST" ...
"CEIL" ...
"CEILING" ...
"CHAR_LENGTH" ...
"CHARACTER_LENGTH" ...
"CLASSIFIER" ...
"COALESCE" ...
"COLLECT" ...
"CONVERT" ...
"COUNT" ...
"COVAR_POP" ...
"COVAR_SAMP" ...
"CUME_DIST" ...
"CURRENT" ...
"CURRENT_CATALOG" ...
"CURRENT_DATE" ...
"CURRENT_DEFAULT_TRANSFORM_GROUP" ...
"CURRENT_PATH" ...
"CURRENT_ROLE" ...
"CURRENT_SCHEMA" ...
"CURRENT_TIME" ...
"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ...
"CURRENT_USER" ...
"CURSOR" ...
"DATE" ...
"DELETE" ...
"DENSE_RANK" ...
"DESCRIBE" ...
"ELEMENT" ...
"EVERY" ...
"EXISTS" ...
"EXP" ...
"EXPLAIN" ...
"EXTRACT" ...
"FALSE" ...
"FIRST_VALUE" ...
"FLOOR" ...
"FUSION" ...
"GROUPING" ...
"HOUR" ...
"INSERT" ...
"INTERSECTION" ...
"INTERVAL" ...
"JSON_ARRAY" ...
"JSON_ARRAYAGG" ...
"JSON_EXISTS" ...
"JSON_OBJECT" ...
"JSON_OBJECTAGG" ...
"JSON_QUERY" ...
"JSON_VALUE" ...
"LAG" ...
"LAST_VALUE" ...
"LEAD" ...
"LEFT" ...
"LN" ...
"LOCALTIME" ...
"LOCALTIMESTAMP" ...
"LOWER" ...
"MATCH_NUMBER" ...
"MAX" ...
"MERGE" ...
"MIN" ...
"MINUTE" ...
"MOD" ...
"MONTH" ...
"MULTISET" ...
"NEW" ...
"NEXT" ...
"NOT" ...
"NTH_VALUE" ...
"NTILE" ...
"NULL" ...
"NULLIF" ...
"OCTET_LENGTH" ...
"OVERLAY" ...
"PERCENT_RANK" ...
"PERIOD" ...
"POSITION" ...
"POWER" ...
"PREV" ...
"RANK" ...
"REGR_COUNT" ...
"REGR_SXX" ...
"REGR_SYY" ...
"RESET" ...
"RIGHT" ...
"ROW" ...
"ROW_NUMBER" ...
"RUNNING" ...
"SECOND" ...
"SELECT" ...
"SESSION_USER" ...
"SET" ...
"SOME" ...
"SPECIFIC" ...
"SQRT" ...
"STDDEV_POP" ...
"STDDEV_SAMP" ...
"SUBSTRING" ...
"SUM" ...
"SYSTEM_USER" ...
"TABLE" ...
"TIME" ...
"TIMESTAMP" ...
"TRANSLATE" ...
"TRIM" ...
"TRUE" ...
"TRUNCATE" ...
"UNKNOWN" ...
"UPDATE" ...
"UPPER" ...
"UPSERT" ...
"USER" ...
"VALUES" ...
"VAR_POP" ...
"VAR_SAMP" ...
"WITH" ...
"YEAR" ...
<UNSIGNED_INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
<APPROX_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
<DECIMAL_NUMERIC_LITERAL> ...
<BINARY_STRING_LITERAL> ...
<QUOTED_STRING> ...
<PREFIXED_STRING_LITERAL> ...
<UNICODE_STRING_LITERAL> ...
"(" ...
<LBRACE_D> ...
<LBRACE_T> ...
<LBRACE_TS> ...
<LBRACE_FN> ...
"?" ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
<BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
<QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
<BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
 ...
<UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...

```
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.generateParseException(SqlParserImpl.java:32563)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.jj_consume_token(SqlParserImpl.java:32377)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.SqlStmt(SqlParserImpl.java:3679)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.SqlStmtEof(SqlParserImpl.java:3691)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.parseSqlStmtEof(SqlParserImpl.java:197)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:161)
... 7 more
```

org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Non-query expression encountered in illegal context
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.convertException(SqlParserImpl.java:365)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.normalizeException(SqlParserImpl.java:150)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.handleException(SqlParser.java:148)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:163)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:178)
at com.apporchid.cloudseer.db.qry.helper.TestMultiThreadSafe.lambda$5(TestMultiThreadSafe.java:142)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteException: Non-query expression encountered in illegal context
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:457)
at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInst.ex(Resources.java:550)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:857)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.newContextException(SqlUtil.java:842)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.checkNonQueryExpression(SqlParserImpl.java:309)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.Expression3(SqlParserImpl.java:14388)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.Expression2b(SqlParserImpl.java:14057)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.Expression2(SqlParserImpl.java:14098)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.Expression(SqlParserImpl.java:14029)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.LeafQueryOrExpr(SqlParserImpl.java:14006)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.QueryOrExpr(SqlParserImpl.java:13478)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.OrderedQueryOrExpr(SqlParserImpl.java:481)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.SqlStmt(SqlParserImpl.java:3653)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.SqlStmtEof(SqlParserImpl.java:3691)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.parseSqlStmtEof(SqlParserImpl.java:197)
at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:161)
... 7 more

Comment: Is there any reason you can't construct a new parser object for each thread?

Comment: Also, if you're asking about exceptions you're encountering, it would be helpful to post these exceptions.

Comment: @MichaelMior updated my post with exception details.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about thread-safety of the parser, but is there any reason you can't just construct a new parser on each thread? I don't think the memory overhead will be significant.

Comment: @Michael Mior, that is causing me little bit of extra time each time

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety is not an explicit design goal of the parser so you shouldn't count on it being thread-safe. If you are finding this to be a serious problem, I would suggest starting a conversation on the Calcite mailing list (dev@calcite.apache.org) to discuss possible solutions which may require changes to Calcite itself.